# Can I change the appearance of an html image during hover without a second image?

Tags: html, css, image

Is there a way to change the appearance of an icon (ie. contrast / luminosity) when I hover the cursor, without requiring a second image file (or without requiring a hidden portion of the image)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here's some good information about image opacity and transparency with CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp).

So to make an image with opacity 50%, you'd do this:

```
<img src="image.png" style="opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50)" />
```

The **opacity:** part is how Firefox does it, and it's a value between 0.0 and 1.0. **filter:** is how IE does it, and it's a value from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 9):

You don't use an img tag, but an element with a background-image css attribute and set the background-position on hover.  IE requires an 'a' tag as a parent element for the :hover selector.  They are called css sprites.

[A great article explaining how to use CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/).

Comment: IE7+ supports the :hover pseudo selector on all elements.

Comment: Actually, the article doesn't really explain what the advantage of CSS sprites is. I imagine that the point is faster loading of new pages (because you "trick" the browser into downloading all images at once).

Answer (score 6):

Here's some code to play with. Basic idea: put all possible states of the picture into one big image, set a "window size", that's smaller than the image; move the window around using `background-position`.

```css
#test {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;  /* window */
  height: 337px; /*  size  */
  background: url(http://vi.sualize.us/thumbs/08/09/01/fashion,indie,inspiration,portrait-f825c152cc04c3dbbb6a38174a32a00f_h.jpg) no-repeat; /* put the image */
  border: 1px solid red; /* for debugging */
  text-indent: -1000px; /* hide the text */
}

#test:hover {
  background-position: -250px 0; /* on mouse over move the window to a different part of the image */
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="test">a button</a>
```

Comment: FWIW This is commonly referred to as a "sprite". http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually see things done with smaller images such as buttons it that only a certain portion of the image is shown. Then many states of the picture will make up a larger picture which gets shifted around behind the visible port. I'll delete this when someone has code.