# How to change the color of an image on hover

Tags: html, css

I need to change the background color of an image. The image is a circle image with white background, I need when you hover over it change the background of the circle image to blue. I need only the circle to be change.

My HTML code is

```
<div class="fb-icon">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/mypage" target="_blank">
<img src="images/fb_normal.png" alt="Facebook">
</a>
</div>
```

In CSS I wrote:

```
.fb-icon:hover {
    background: blue;
}
```

The above code gives me blue color but as a frame around the circle icon. what I need is to change the background of the circle itself. Imagine it's like a signal it's white when you hover by mouse it goes to blue.

Please I need a solution if it can be done by CSS or whatever. Sorry if I make it too long.

The problem: [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2u9h5jd&s=5)

Comment: is your png image a white circle with transparent background? If you can post a link for us to check it out it would be really helpful because your issue is not very clear.

Comment: You're saying you want the *image* to change, not the background color, correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the appearance of an html image during hover without a second image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290/can-i-change-the-appearance-of-an-html-image-during-hover-without-a-second-image) Couldn't find a better post that has the answer you want, but see the 2 answer about using sprites (not the accepted one).

Comment: @Juank The link for the image, [link](http://tinypic.com/r/15yfaf7/5)

Comment: @Madmartigan I put a link for the problem. I hope it will be clear if you can help me.

Comment: That link appears to no longer work ....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ideally you should use a transparent PNG with the circle in white and the background of the image transparent. Then you can set the `background-color` of the `.fb-icon` to blue on hover. So you're CSS would be:

```
fb-icon{
    background:none;
}

fb-icon:hover{
    background:#0000ff;
}
```

Additionally, if you don't want to use PNG's you can also use a sprite and alter the background position. A sprite is one large image with a collection of smaller images which can be used as a background image by changing the background position. So for eg, if your original circle image with the white background is **100px X 100px**, you can increase the height of the image to **100px X 200px**, so that the top half is the original image with the white background, while the lower half is the new image with the blue background. Then you set setup your CSS as:

```
fb-icon{
    background:url('path/to/image/image.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}

fb-icon:hover{
    background:url('path/to/image/image.png') no-repeat 0 -100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help i use your idea, with the following code
.fb-icon a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: url('../images/email.png') no-repeat scroll center center #679d40;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 62px;
 height: 62px;
    border-radius: 32px;
 text-indent: -99999px;
}

.fb-icon:hover a {
    background: url('../images/email.png') no-repeat scroll center center #000000;
}

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late but I came across this post.

It's not perfect but here's what I do.

HTML Code

```
<div class="showcase-menu-social"><img class="margin-left-20" src="images/graphics/facebook-50x50.png" alt="facebook-50x50" width="50" height="50" /><img class="margin-left-20" src="images/graphics/twitter-50x50.png" alt="twitter-50x50" width="50" height="50" /><img class="margin-left-20" src="images/graphics/youtube-50x50.png" alt="youtube-50x50" width="50" height="50" /></div>
```

CSS Code

```
.showcase-menu {
  margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    background-color: #C37500;
    behavior: url(/css/border-radius.htc);
  border-radius: 20px;
    }

.showcase-menu-social img:hover {
  background-color: #C37500;
  opacity:0.7 !important;
  filter:alpha(opacity=70) !important; /* For IE8 and earlier */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px #000000 !important;
}
```

Now my border radius of 20px matches up exactly with the image border radius.  As you can see the .showcase-menu has the same background as the .showcase-menu-social.  What this does is to allow the 'opacity' to take effect and no 'square' background or border shows, thus the image slightly reduces it's saturation on hover.

It's a nice effect and does give the viewer the feedback that the image is in focus.  I'm fairly sure on a darker background, it would have even a better effect.

The nice thing is that this is valid HTML-CSS code and will validate.  To be honest, it should work on non-image elements just as good as images.

Enjoy!

Comment: If you have a class called `margin-left-20` you might as well be saying `style="margin-left: 20px;"`

Comment: What does the behavior style do?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution would be to use the new CSS mask image functionality which works in everything apart from IE (still not supported in IE11). This would be more versatile and maintainable than some of the other solutions suggested here. You could also more generally use SVG. 
e.g.

```
item { mask: url('/mask-image.png'); }
```

There is an example of using a mask image here:

```
http://codepen.io/zerostyle/pen/tHimv
```

and lots of examples here:

```
http://codepen.io/yoksel/full/fsdbu/
```

Answer (score 1):

If the icon is from Font Awesome (https://fontawesome.com/icons/)
then you could tap into the color css property to change it's background.

```
fb-icon{
color:none;
}

fb-icon:hover{
color:#0000ff;
}
```

This is irrespective of the color it had. So you could use an entirely different color in its usual state and define another in its active state.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then it would be easier if you gave your image a transparent background and set the background container's background-color property without having to use filters and so on.

http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html

Shows you how to use filters in IE. Maybe if you leverage something from that. Not very cross-browser compatible though. Another option might be to have two images and use them as background-images (rather than img tags), swap one out after another using the :hover pseudo selector.

Comment: The [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2u9h5jd&s=5) I need to color only the fb icon which the circle, can you help me about that ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this:

Get the image with the transparent circle - http://i39.tinypic.com/15s97vd.png
Put that image in a html element and change that element's background color via css. This way you get the logo with the circle in the color defined in the stylesheet.

The html

```
<div class="badassColorChangingLogo">
    <img src="http://i39.tinypic.com/15s97vd.png" /> 
    Or download the image and change the path to the downloaded image in your machine
</div>
```

The css

```
div.badassColorChangingLogo{
    background-color:white;
}
div.badassColorChangingLogo:hover{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Keep in mind that this wont work on non-alpha capable browsers like ie6, and ie7. for ie you can use a js fix. Google ddbelated png fix and you can get the script.

Comment: I understand you do your best to help me. So I will do my best to make it clear for you to help. I'm sorry I don't clear all the picture for you. please check that [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2u9h5jd&s=5). Now I need to hover over fb circle and should be blue. Your solution make it white square so the box dose not appear and when i hover i got a blue square around the fb. so what i need only the circle to be blue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the background-color property instead of the background property in your CSS.
So your code will look like this:

`.fb-icon:hover {`
    `background: blue;`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use a svg image in which the background would be a white rect and the foreground the circle, and set the hover property to the bg. It's a vector graphic image so it will look fine on any screen size, not to mention that svg is meant to be used in the web. This svg should be just of some bytes and its rendered better than any raster or bitmap image.