# CSS filter to change color of image pixels on hover

Tags: html, css, css-filters

Is there a CSS filter that can change all the pixels of an image to a different color?

I found this one but it is not the same:

[How to change the color of an image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047134/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-image-on-hover)

I found this guide and it goes from grayscale to color or color to grayscale.

https://robinroelofsen.com/change-images-grayscale-color-hover

It would probably look like the following:

```
.myClass :hover {
    filter: color(blue);
}
```

Requirements: Use CSS (no JS), change the filter of existing image pixels to another color.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: Like pixel by pixel each is just some random color? Like you say "this one but not the same" what's the difference you're looking for? Not sure what you're asking exactly but if it's outside of [some specs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_effects.asp) would maybe help to show an example of what you're after.

Comment: you mean make all the image **one** color?

Comment: Yea are you just after maybe an overlay to give like a sepia color effect?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes. if an image is red then I want to make it blue. A `tint` or `hue` like filter may work but I did not see one. or not a straight forward one. there was a hue rotation that took a rotation number like `filter: rotation(90)` but i'm looking for `filter: hue(lightblue)`

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942954/8620333

Comment: Sounds like a job for [hue-rotate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate()) since you explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use  filter: hue-rotate(xdeg)  where x is a number between 0 and 359 and deg is for degrees. This filter rotates the hue of the any element, not just images, on a certain number of degrees. It uses the HSLcolor scheme.

```css
 html{
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
background:red;
     filter:hue-rotate(180deg);
}

div {
background:#0000ff;
}

h1 {
background:#00ff00;
color:#ffff00;
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="css/light.css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme-link">
</head>
<body>
<h3>
<b>This is what I can do 
</b>
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use svg filters as shown [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/). If you are want to play with different filters you can try so [here](https://yoksel.github.io/svg-gradient-map/#/).